# Cytoscape.js, How to make node label always above the graph?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I constructed a network in cytoscape js, I found that the labels of compound nodes are always covered by the edges. How should I keep the labels always above over other elements in the graph?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

(1) A label is grouped with its corresponding element.  This avoids label clutter with close elements, and it respects the relative z-indices specified for the elements.

(2) A label is drawn on top of its corresponding element.

(3) Elements are drawn in order of (compound depth, z-index), with compound depth being the "more significant digit".

(4) An edge necessarily has the compound depth of the deepest connected node plus 0.5 such that edges connected to compound nodes are shown properly.

Because of (1) and (4) in particular, naturally edges can overlap labels of compounds in the hierarchy of the source and target.  You can style and position your compound labels such that overlap is minimised, and you can also set the layout parameters appropriately for your data such that overlap is minimised.  You may consider having semitransparent edges, as well.

It is not possible to have labels on top of everything all the time as you suggest, as that would contradict the z ordering specification.